# Are vue components nested objects when compiled?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Are Vue's Single file components for e.g `App, QuotesList, QuoteItem` (each an SFC) nested objects when compiled, for example:

**Diagrammatic Representation**

```
App(Parent)
 |
  QuotesList (child of App)
         | 
          QuoteItem (child of QuotesList)
```

**JS Object representation**

```
var App = {
    quotesList : {
        quoteItem: {..}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not exactly. actually each vue component is an object containing the vue 
properties plus properties that you have defined (data properties, life cycle hooks, watchers, etc).

but there is still a way to get information about the components relationship:

the vue component object has references to its children component, which you can access via `this.$children`, and has a reference to its parent component, available via `this.$parent`.